# How to get spring boot cloud/actuator to support prometheus Exemplars?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-sleuth

The Exemplars support essentially adds the trace-id to metrics that are being scraped. I found a tutorial on how would it work with GoLang[1] but cannot figure out how to do this with spring boot libraries/functionalities. I know that Prometheus Java Client supports it as described at [2] but not sure how to get it to work with Springboot.

1. https://vbehar.medium.com/using-prometheus-exemplars-to-jump-from-metrics-to-traces-in-grafana-249e721d4192
2. https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/pull/615

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Exemplars are supported by Micrometer and Spring Cloud Sleuth.**

I'm not 100% sure I get your question right: I'm assuming you are talking about the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint.

The support for metrics in Spring is provided by [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) that also supports [Prometheus](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus) and Spring Boot "just" sets up an actuator endpoint for it.

So the real question is: does Micrometer support exemplars? Right now it does not and we haven't had anyone asking for it so far ([this issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2627) is a little bit connected). <del>So if you want this feature, please open an [issue(Enhancement request)](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/new/choose) on GitHub.</del>

**Update:** I opened an issue for this: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/2672, please feel free to +1 or chime-in.

Adding exemplars support in Micrometer is not the end of the story, we need to add support for Spring Cloud Sleuth too and solve a few other potential issues.

Until this is implemented, I guess your best bet is using the prometheus client.